# Passing arguments from session to javascript in a JSP file

Tags: java, javascript, session, dwr

I am creating a web app and I am using LDAP for authentication. In the login page I get a "Name" and "Phone number" from Active directory and I store these two variables in the session. Then it goes to the main page where I grab the values from the session:

```
<%
  Object name = session.getAttribute("name");
  Object ext = session.getAttribute("ext");
%>
```

I am also using DWR to be able to use the classes I have in the backend such as a class for database operations called DBOps. Inside DBOps there is a method that will update a phone number.

And then in the JSP file I have a javascript to handle that and it works perfectly fine, except Id'like to pass an argument to the function such as the phone number to update.

This all happens when the user clicks on teh button so I have:

```
<button onclick="updateDN();">Update</button>
```

My question is how can I pass "ext" to updateDN so it would be

```
<button onclick="updateDN(ext);">Update</button>
```

There are many threads that address this problem but I was not able to get any of the solutions to work in my situation. I hope somebody can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Declare
`var ext = '<%= session.getAttribute("ext"); %>'; `

and use it when you call your function

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this works and much simpler. <button onclick='updateDN(<%=ext%>);'></button>

Comment: Happy to help. With that way you could use that variable anywhere in your script in case you needed it in another function. Well, at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the object as a parameter by using the [JSP Expression tag](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag)

```
<button onclick="updateDN(<%=ext%>);">Update</button>
```

Or bypassing the parameter directly from the session object.

```
<button onclick="updateDN(<%=session.getAttribute("ext")%>);">Update</button>
```